# Javascript - order of OnClick

Tags: javascript, vb.net

Please see the code below which is generated on the server side:

```
tc.Attributes.Add("onclick", "location.reload(); this.style.backgroundColor='olivedrab'; open('PrimaryNominalAjax.aspx?USN=" & CStr(objDR("USN")) & "&Requester=" & strUserName & "&Status=" & CStr(intReviewStatus) & "&Reason=-1&Review=" & lngReview & "','_blank','')")
```

When the user clicks on the link on the client side the code reaches the server side page load event in: PrimaryNominalAjax.aspx before it refreshes the current webpage.  Why is this?

Answer (score 0):

location.reload() does not block the execution of other javascript. So if it takes say, 5 seconds to reload a page, animations etc can continue.

Are you trying to get your site to: Reload, then change color, then open another page? I don't think you will be able to accomplish this using the method you have above. Once the page reloads, it has lost all knowledge of state from before it was reloaded. So after the reload, the page wont know that the tc button was clicked.

You are probably better navigating to the current page with a url parameter

```
location.href = location.href + "?button=tc";
```

Then in the onload event, check if that value is in the URL, then change the background color and open the second page. Something along the lines of:

```
if(location.search === "button=tc")
{
    // change color 
    // open page
}
```